# Speeding up deletes that have joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

i am running a stored procedure to delete data from two tables:

```
delete from TESTING_testresults
from TESTING_testresults
inner join TESTING_QuickLabDump
on TESTING_QuickLabDump.quicklabdumpid = TESTING_TestResults.quicklabdumpid
where TESTING_quicklabdump.[Specimen ID]=@specimen



delete from TESTING_QuickLabDump
from TESTING_Quicklabdump
where [specimen id]=@specimen
```

one table is 60m rows and the other is about 2m rows

the procedure takes about 3 seconds to run.

is there any way i can speed this up? perhaps using `EXISTS`?

meaning `IF EXISTS...THEN DELETE` - because the delete should not be occurring every single time

something like this

if `@specimen exists` in `TESTING_QuickLabDump` then do the procedure with the two deletes

thank you !!!

Comment: Have you determined if it is the query (to find the rows to delete) or the actual deletion of the rows that takes the most time?

Comment: If indexing or other tuning efforts don't help and this is posing a real problem you may want to look into table partitioning which will allow you to perform deletions without the overhead.

Comment: Maybe I'm reading between the lines here, but are you trying to delete the data row-by-row?  If so, try a set-based approach.  That is, create a temp table that holds all the SpeciminIDs to delete and join on it.

Comment: Set results to be shown in text, `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON` then `GO` then run your query then `GO` then `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL OFF`. Post results here, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a table with 60 mil rows I would definitely look into partitioning the data horizontally and/or vertically.  If it's time-sensitive data then you ought to be able to move old data into a history table.  That's usually the first and most obvious thing people do so I would imagine if that were a possibility you would have already done it.

If there are many columns then it would definitely benefit you to denormalize the data into multiple tables.  If you did this, I would suggest renaming the tables and creating a view of all the partitioned tables named after the original table.  Doing that should ensure existing code isn't broken.

If you 'really' want to fine tune the speed then you should look into getting a faster hard drive and learn a little about hard drives work.  Whether the data is stored towards the inner or outer section of the hd will affect speed of access slightly for example.  And solid state hard drives have come a long way so you might look into getting one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting the query probably wont help speeding this up. Use the [profiler](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Using_SQL_Server_Profiler) to find out which parts of the query are slow. For this, make it profiler output the [execution plan](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/query-execution-plan-analysis/). Then, try adding appropriate indexes. Perhaps one or both tables could use an index over `[specimen id]`.

Comment: Also add an index on quicklabdumpid

Comment: thanks so much. can you please tell me user23498293874 how does what the profiler show map (or relate to) which indexes should be added? i understand what you are saying but i do not know how to implement it

Comment: Make the profiler output the [execution plan](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2006/query-execution-plan-analysis/). I also remember hearing about a tool that would suggest indexes automatically based on the queries you execute.

Comment: Yes, when ssms outputs the execution plan it also shows some information about potentially missing indexes and you can right click on it to get it to generate them for you (well, generate some code that you'll have to edit slightly but it's obvious how to do).

If you don't see anything about missing indexes then it means they're already there or it otherwise doesn't see how any additional indexes would help.

Comment: +1 for not involving the profiler :-) This should be more convenient for the OP's use case

Answer (score 1):

Beside indexing "obvious" fields, also look in your database schema and check if you have any FOREIGN KEYs whose ON DELETE CASCADE or SET NULL might be triggered by your delete (unlike Oracle, MS SQL Server will tend to show these in the execution plan). Fortunately, this is usually fairly easy to fix by indexing the child endpoint of the FOREIGN KEY.

Also check if you have any expensive triggers.